# How can I stop the jquery carousel through an onmouseover event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I use the carousel from http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm and it plays automatically.
You can find the script that plays the carousel (the non-minified one here: http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/js/jquery.carousel.js )
I want the carousel to stop on mouseover event.

I found a function called "stopautoslide(env)", but have no clue how to put that to use. I've tried a few things, but it didn't do what I want it to do.
The onmouse events would go inside one of the slides, in which I load a video. So if people would move their mouse over that slide to click on the video to get that started, it should stop the video.
(and yes, I've googled for it, without result. I've contacted the maker, without result..)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
I tried the first answer, which you view here: http://www.altrient.com/cgi-bin/start.cgi/testpurpose/1test.html
(which is to add $('div.caroussel').bind('mouseover',function(){$('div.caroussel').carousel({autoSlide:false});}); to the li.. )
The problem is, that.. I should explain a little bit further how this carousel works: The carousel is set up as a simple div and within that div a list structure (ul, li, you know how). At the bottom of the page, you run a script to actually start that carousel.

Comment: could you show us what you tried?  is your problem with using the mouseover/onmouse events or with stopping the carousel?

Comment: I would use a Carousel plugin with a pause on hover option already built-in... there are loads of them.  jCarousel, jCarousel Lite, Nivo Slider, etc.

Comment: @alonisser: My problem is WHAT I should put in the onmousover event to stop the carousel. So.. what it would come down to:the problem is basically how to stop the carousel.

Comment: @Malachi tried to look into the page and it just crushed my computer.. could you please post the html here?

Comment: @actually my answer does stop the carousel, but then you should put something alternative into the div..

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? Can I use your answer litteraly (by using a different divname basically)? And if so, does that div need to exist already? In other words: could you give an example? (also because I'm confused when you say "put something alternative into the div.)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do:

```
$("div.yourdiv").bind('mouseover',function(){
   $("div.yourdiv").carousel({autoSlide:false});//this is what you should use in the onmouseover inside the li
});
```

good luck

**edit: answering malachi question**: the answer is in the code above: calling the carousel plugin with `{autoSlide=false}` parameter.

**edit**:you should be adding something instead of the carousel div, after stopping the carousel.. with .append()

Comment: What I meant was.. one of li's would look kinda like this:
`<li>contents<li>`
`<li onmouseover="">contents<li>`
`<li>contents<li>`
In which the middle one would have something in that onmouseover to stop the carousel from playing.

Comment: Alonisser, thank you for your reply. I tried this (see also my edit in the question for further explanation and an example)... and it basically starts over the whole carousel within the carousel, every time I would do the mouseover... I think I've tried something similar before, because I also had it 'start over' the carousel (as in, having the back and forward button reappearing, etc. although my try was not as specific as your answer)...